# Consistent random ordering in a MySQL query

Tags: mysql, random

I have a database of pictures and I want to let visitors browse the pictures. I have one "next" and one "previous" link.

But what I want is to show every visitor anther order of the pictures. How can I do that? If I will use ORDER BY RANDOM() I will show sometimes duplicate images.

Can someone help me please? Thank you!

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can try to use seed in random function:

`SELECT something
FROM somewhere
ORDER BY rand(123)`

123 is a seed. Random should return the same values.

Comment: What's the use of ordering by a function that always returns the same value?

Comment: Try it before saying.You can generate a seed for a scope of session or other scope and use this to paginate the same results.

Comment: Acually, izi's got a point. If you can keep this seed unique for each visitor, it will solve the problem. I had no idea about the existence of the seed, but it's quite interesting.

Comment: @izi, do you happen to know in what version of MySQL the seed appeared?

Comment: @Wouter, try this: `CREATE TABLE test (i INT);`, then insert some values in the table, then use `SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY RAND(1)`. Repeat that and you will see the results in the same random order. Try then with `RAND(2)`.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean there. If you run `SELECT RAND(123)` it initiates the randomizer and you'll get the first value of a sequence.  If you have multiple rows it does indeed return different values for each row.

Comment: Izi, I want to undo my downvote here, but it doesn't let me unless the answer is edited. If you edit it, i'll change it to upvote. Sorry guys.

Comment: Seed is a number which you use to initialize random sequence. If you use constantly the same randomizer initialized with the specific seed you will get consistent results. Try it on some dataset to see how it works.

Comment: I've added a space to your answer so that I could change my vote (if the answer is unchanged you can't change a vote somehow). Good answer, I mistakenly thought that RAND(seed) would always return the same value.

Comment: @rdineiu: The seed has been around for as long as I can remember (MySQL 4 has it for sure; dunno about MySQL 3). Btw, I've contributed a third alternative, which works around the performance implications.

Comment: Thank you! How can I add a next or previous link?

Comment: @Nathaniel use LIMIT keyword. For example LIMIT 0, 10 will give you only first ten results of the query. Check some thread about pagination.

Comment: Does anyone know how different the results will be once the number of rows is altered? For example adding a new row or deleting an existing row? Will the same seed's results suddenly change drastically?

Answer (score 4):

The problem arises from the fact that each page will run `RAND()` again and has no way of knowing if the returned pictures have already been returned before. You would have to compose your query in such a way that you can filter out the pictures already presented on the previous pages, so that `RAND()` will have fewer options to choose from.

An idea would be to randomize the pictures, select the IDs, store the IDs in the session, then `SELECT` using those IDs. This way, each user will have the pictures randomized, but they will be able to paginate through them without re-randomizing them on each page.

So, something like:

1. `SELECT id FROM pictures ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT x` if you don't have the IDs in the session already
2. Store the IDs in the session
3. `SELECT ... FROM pictures WHERE id IN (IDs from session) LIMIT x`

Another idea is to store in session the IDs that the user already saw and filter them out. For example:

1. `SELECT ... FROM pictures ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT x` if the session doesn't contain any ID
2. Append the IDs from the current query to the session
3. `SELECT ... FROM pictures WHERE id NOT IN (IDs from session) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT x`

Another way seems to be to use a seed, as [izi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6160850/consistent-random-ordering-in-a-mysql-query#answer-6160938) points out. I have to say I didn't know about the seed, but it seems to return the exact same results for the exact same value of the seed. So, run your usual query and use `RAND(seed)` instead of `RAND()`, where "seed" is a unique string or number. You can use the session ID as a seed, because it's guaranteed to be unique for each visitor.

Comment: +1 You're the only one who seems to understand the underlying problem that the OP decribes. Indeed, you need to store the ordering for the session, or if the user logs in, for the user.  Basically this is not a mysql query problem, but a problem of how to maintain a state between page requests.

Comment: This is a valid solution, but izi's answer is a *much* better alternative.

Comment: I agree with Denis. Seems to be what the seed was made for.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! How can I store the IDs? With thousands of cookies?

Comment: @Nathaniel, use izi's suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

You can seed the random function as suggested by izi, or keep track of visited images vs non-visited images as suggested by rdineiu.

I'd like to stress that neither option will perform well, however. Either will lead you to sorting your entire table (or the part of it of interest) using an arbitrary criteria and extracting the top `n` rows, possibly with an offset. It'll be dreadfully slow.

Thus, consider for a moment how important it is that *every* visitor should get a different image order. Probably, it'll be not *that* important, as long as things look random. Assuming this is the case, consider this alternative...

Add an extra `float` field to your table, call it `sort_ord`. **Add an index on it**. On every insert or update, assign it a random value. The point here is to end up with a seemingly random order (from the visitor's standpoint) without compromising performance.

Such a setup will allow you to grab the top `n` rows and paginate your images using an index, rather than by sorting your entire table.

At your option, have a cron job periodically set a new value:

```
update yourtable
set sort_ord = rand();
```

Also at your option, create several such fields and assign one to visitors when they visit your site (cookie or session).

Comment: Hrm, this means that *all* visitors will see the same thing... But then again, as you say, it matters a lot what the priority is. If the table contains just a few hundred rows, the site is visited by a few hundred users a day, and you *need* all visitors to see something different, then `ORDER BY RAND` will do what's needed, without seeing any performance problem.

Comment: That's the whole point, yes: at the core of the idea is that they're not sitting next to one another, so they won't know they're viewing the images in the same manner.

Comment: Also, this might introduce a concurrency issue. If a user sees page 1, then the cron runs, the values will be changed, and the user might see the same results again on page 2.

Comment: Indeed it would, at 4am when the cron job runs. As a site designer, I'd be quite happy to live with that side effect. :-)

Comment: Hehe, yeah, but unfortunately when it's 4 AM for you, it might very well be 2 PM for 100 other users...

Comment: If the concurrency is that big of a problem (I think it isn't) there always is the possibility to be using two fields and rotate their use every 12h. You assign the first in the session; at the 12h mark you start assigning the second and continue to use the first in for open sessions; at the 22h mark you refresh the first; at the 24h you similarly rotate back to the first.

Answer (score 1):

This will solve:

```
SELECT DISTINCT RAND() as rnd, [rest of your query] ORDER BY rnd;
```

Comment: This is what the OP is already doing. The problem is probably that every time the user requests a page and the query that you suggest is ran, each row is renumbered, so you'll get the same image anyway.

Answer (score 1):

**Use RAND(SEED)**. From the docs: "*If a constant integer argument N is specified, it is used as the seed value.*" (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand).

In the example above the result order is always the same. You simply change the seed (351) and you get a new random order.

```
SELECT * FROM your_table ORDER BY RAND(351);
```

You can to change the seed every time the user hits the first page.

Answer (score -3):

Without seeing the SQL I'd guess you could try SELECT DISTINCT...

Comment: He means `SELECT DISTINCT image FROM images ORDER BY RANDOM()`

Comment: I don't like downvoting, so I won't do that. But this answer sends the OP in the wrong direction.