# MySQL - Random sort by context

Tags: php, mysql, random, sql-order-by

I have a sql query which get all articles from a table. This list is ordered by category, price and delay.

Some articles have the same price, the same category and the same delay so they alway come in the same order. My problem is : why one article would always come before the other if they have the same caracteristics ? I need to shuffle them following a random element which is saved in a cookie, so i can always get the same "shuffle" for a given user ?

**Exemple**

I have 100 articles, among them 5 have the same specs (we call them art1, art2, art3, art4, and art5).

following my ordering, i get this list:

```
art1
art2
art3
art4
art5
```

But as they have the same specs, i need to shuffle them randomly for a given visitor, for example, one user would get this list :

```
art2
art5
art4
art1
art3
```

the following user

```
art4
art3
art1
art5
art2
```

etc...

The trick is : I need to remember how i can get each random order, so i can get exactly the same order for a given user if he comes back later in the day (the cookie will expire daily).

I known some website use a context variable to shuffle, but how to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add another order field using `ORDER BY category, price, delay, RAND(seed)` and adding your data from the cookie as seed to the random function.

Then you will always get the same sequence of numbers for your user as long as the seed does not change.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/6160938/1634286

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of articles talking about how to randomly pick records in MySQL.

Using ORDER BY RAND is very slow. Better if using PHP code instead.

Once you get the records, save the IDs into cookie/session so you can restore them later