# Rand() Query should produces same result

Tags: mysql

I want to Execute a Query with  Order by Rand(). The result set produced by this query should be same when i execute the same query again in other place of my Project. the result set order shoul not changed.. can any one provide solutions for this..

For Examples
Consider a Table tbl

```
S.No  name

1     Mani

2     Raja

3     raj
```

Now If i Execute a Query `"SELECT * FROM tbl order by RAND()";` it may produce the result set as follow.

```
S.No    name

2       Raja

1       Mani

3       raj.
```

When i run the same query again in the another Place of my project. i wants, it should return the same result set as above.. When i close and re open my application , result set should be change.. but still the close of Application.. result set should be same as of first it produces

Comment: What's the point of using rand then?

Comment: ORDER BY <number> specifies which COLUMN you want to sort on. ORDER BY 1 would sort ascending on S.No and ORDER BY 2 would sort ascending on Name. What is random is which column you are sorting on.

Comment: When i close and re open  my application , result set should be change.. but still the close of Application.. result set should be same as of first it produces

Comment: possible duplicate of [Consistent random ordering in a MySQL query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6160850/consistent-random-ordering-in-a-mysql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE : [**Click for Example**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4d94c/1)

You can use `RAND(3)` which will produce the same random output.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl order by RAND(3)
```

For details about RAND() function please refer [**this**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand)

Comment: @MANIKANDAN use RAND(3) and it will return the result with same order

Comment: it is seed value to generate random number, you can give any seed number, and it will always order the result in same way

Answer (score 0):

The ORDER BY RAND() operation actually re-queries each row of your table, assigns a random number ID and then delivers the results... so you may not get same resultset when you query again 
I suggest to avoid rand()
refer:
http://www.webtrenches.com/post.cfm/avoid-rand-in-mysql