# How to recover the users I published randomly when I click on my profile to display them again when I return php

Tags: php

Hello I posted the users randomly on my site but when I click on a user to see his profile I would like when I return I fall back on the same users. PLEASE HELP ME

This is the code I typed for displaying users and now I would like to repost all the users I've already posted randomly

// This query will be used to display all users randomly

```
$listsAllUsers = $db->prepare("SELECT users1.id, username, sex, country, years, city, 
                                   regionOuProvince, titleOuSlogan, about, 
                                   orientation, looking_for, civil_status, img_original FROM users1 
                                   LEFT JOIN users2 ON users1.id = users2.user_id
                                   LEFT JOIN pictures ON users1.id = pictures.user_id
                                   WHERE pictures.active_profile = ?
                                   ORDER BY RAND() $limit");
    $listsAllUsers->execute(['2']);
    $listAllUsers = $listsAllUsers->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

<?php if ($data->display_user_fetch == '1'): ?>
            <div class="container">
                <ul class="usersFetch">
                    <center>
                        <?php if (count($listAllUsers) != 0): ?>
                            <?php foreach ($listAllUsers as $listAllUser): ?>
                                <li style="text-align:center;">
                                    <div class="userFetchBloc">
                                        <a href="<?= WEBSITE_NAME_URL ?>/profile/<?= strtolower($listAllUser->username) ?>">
                                            <img src="/<?= $listAllUser->img_original ?>" class="img_user_fetch_bloc" style="width: 100%;" alt="Meeting <?= $listAllUser->username ?> On <?= WEBSITE_NAME ?>">
                                        </a>
                                        <div class="fetchInfosUserStandardProfile">
                                            <span class="fetchInfosUserText">
                                                &nbsp;<span class="infosUserText2"><?= $listAllUser->username ?>, </span><?= date('Y') - $listAllUser->years ?> old&nbsp;<br>
                                                &nbsp;<?= $listAllUser->city ?><span class="infosUserText">, <?= $listAllUser->regionOuProvince ?></span>&nbsp;
                                                <span class="infosUserText2"><br>&nbsp;<?= NbrePictures($listAllUser->id) ?> photo<?= NbrePictures($listAllUser->id) > 1 ? 's' : ''; ?>&nbsp;</span>
                                            </span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="all_necessary_infos">
                                        <div>
                                            <b><?= $listAllUser->titleOuSlogan ?></b>
                                        </div>
                                        <em><?= $listAllUser->civil_status ?> <?= $listAllUser->sex ?> of <?= date('Y') - $listAllUser->years ?> years looking for <?= verify_looking_for($listAllUser->id, $listAllUser->sex) ?> for <?= $listAllUser->orientation ?></em>
                                        <div class="wideDiv">
                                            <?= $listAllUser->about ?>
                                        </div>
                                            <strong>Meet</strong> <a style="color: #be0210;" href="<?= WEBSITE_NAME_URL ?>/meet-<?= lcfirst($listAllUser->sex) ?>-<?= suppr_accents($listAllUser->city) ?>" style="color:#be0210;"><?= $listAllUser->city ?></a>, 
                                                <a style="color: #be0210;" href="<?= WEBSITE_NAME_URL ?>/meet-<?= lcfirst($listAllUser->sex) ?>-<?= suppr_accents($listAllUser->regionOuProvince) ?>" style="color:#be0210;"><?= $listAllUser->regionOuProvince ?></a>, 
                                                <a style="color: #be0210;" href="<?= WEBSITE_NAME_URL ?>/meet-<?= lcfirst($listAllUser->sex) ?>-<?= lcfirst($listAllUser->country) ?>" style="color:#be0210;"><?= $listAllUser->country ?></a>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            <?php endforeach ?>
                        <?php else: ?>
                            <p style="text-align: center;">No users on <?= WEBSITE_NAME ?></p>
                        <?php endif ?>
                    </center>
                </ul>
                <?php if (count($listAllUsers) != 0): ?>
                    <div id="pagination" style="position: relative; top: 10px; bottom: 5px;"><?= $pagination ?></div>
                <?php endif ?>
            </div>
        <?php else: ?>
            <?php if (count($listAllUsers) != 0): ?>
                <?php foreach ($listAllUsers as $key => $listAllUser): ?>
                    <div id="user_container_testimony">
                        <div class="userTestimony">
                            <span class="img_message_testimony">
                                <a href="<?= WEBSITE_NAME_URL ?>/profile/<?= strtolower($listAllUser->username) ?>">
                                    <img src="/<?= $listAllUser->img_original ?>" class="img_testimony" alt="This image shows <?= $listAllUser->username ?> meeting on <?= WEBSITE_NAME ?>.">
                                </a>
                            </span>
                            <div class="fetchInfosUserStandardProfileStyle">
                                <span class="fetchInfosUserText">
                                    &nbsp;<span class="infosUserText2"><?= $listAllUser->username ?>, </span><?= date('Y') - $listAllUser->years ?> old&nbsp;<br>
                                    &nbsp;<?= $listAllUser->city ?><span class="infosUserText">, <?= $listAllUser->regionOuProvince ?></span>&nbsp;
                                    <span class="infosUserText2"><br>&nbsp;<?= NbrePictures($listAllUser->id) ?> photo<?= (NbrePictures($listAllUser->id) > 1) ? 's' : '' ?>&nbsp;</span>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="allTestimony">
                                <div class="titleTestimony">
                                    <strong><u><?= $listAllUser->titleOuSlogan ?></u></strong> 
                                </div>
                                <div class="subtitleTestimony">
                                    <span class="describeSubtitleTestimony">
                                        <u><a href="<?= WEBSITE_NAME_URL ?>/profile/<?= strtolower($listAllUser->username) ?>" style="color: #be0210;"><?= $listAllUser->username ?></a></u> <?= $listAllUser->civil_status ?> <?= $listAllUser->sex ?> of <?= date('Y') - $listAllUser->years ?> years looking for <?= verify_looking_for($listAllUser->id, $listAllUser->sex) ?> for <?= $listAllUser->orientation ?>
                                    </span> 
                                </div>
                                <div class="testimony">
                                    <span class="describeTestimony">
                                        <?= mb_strlen($listAllUser->about) > 350 ? substr($listAllUser->about, 0, 350).' <a href="'.WEBSITE_NAME_URL.'/profile/'.strtolower($listAllUser->username).'" style="color: #be0210;">More Read...</a>' : $listAllUser->about ?>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="meetCityRegion">
                                <strong>Meet</strong> <u style="color: #be0210;"><a href="<?= WEBSITE_NAME_URL ?>/meet-<?= lcfirst($listAllUser->sex) ?>-<?= suppr_accents($listAllUser->city) ?>" style="color:#be0210;"><?= $listAllUser->city ?></a></u>, 
                                    <u style="color: #be0210;"><a href="<?= WEBSITE_NAME_URL ?>/meet-<?= lcfirst($listAllUser->sex) ?>-<?= suppr_accents($listAllUser->regionOuProvince) ?>" style="color:#be0210;"><?= $listAllUser->regionOuProvince ?></a></u>, 
                                    <u style="color: #be0210;"><a href="<?= WEBSITE_NAME_URL ?>/meet-<?= lcfirst($listAllUser->sex) ?>-<?= lcfirst($listAllUser->country) ?>" style="color:#be0210;"><?= $listAllUser->country ?></a></u>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php endforeach ?>
                <div id="pagination" style="position: relative; top: 10px; bottom: 5px;"><?= $pagination ?></div>
            <?php else: ?>
                <p style="text-align: center;">You have not traded anything with this user yet.</p>
            <?php endif ?>
        <?php endif ?>
```

I would like you to help me take the users I've already posted randomly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently here is no simple way to "*lock*" the same users set when you use `RAND()` statement for `ORDER` because `RAND` here generate narnodm order every you call SQL query ( = on every page load).

You can use 3 ways:

- Generate random keys to separate column in table and order by it. That can crate random order, bud it fixed during time – it make repeatable views to list.
- Select random list of users as currently and cache that list somewhere and load it later when you back to that page.
- Maybe you car help allo browser cache page with list of user with sending right [HTTP header in request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching).

**Question is why you want to sort it randomly?**

Comment: for my website dating

Comment: I would like to display users in random mode you see it's more interesting ... Here is my site that I'm working on https://shippinglove.shippingmovies.com/

Comment: I really did not understand the three ways you told me

Comment: Give me an example I sent the site link for you

Comment: As I said, your request is not simple. For you case looks most simple way to add Content-Cache header to response to cache page in browser for abou 5 minutes. Look more vore HTTP caching: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching and `header()` function in PHP: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php.

Comment: Option 4: Use a (random) seed value for RAND(), and store only that somewhere (i.e., user session) so that it can be reused the next time.

Comment: @misorude Seed it not guarantee repeatable set of returned records.

Comment: Yes it does. What are you talking about? Even the MySQL manual confirms this: _“One implication of this behavior is that for equal argument values, RAND(N) returns the same value each time, and thus produces a repeatable sequence of column values. ”_

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6160850/consistent-random-ordering-in-a-mysql-query

Comment: I understood. Thank you guys for this help